# How do I encode an image?

Tags: java, php, html, image, encoding

I was reading this blog [http://alexrogan.com](http://alexrogan.com/?p=74) the writer talks about adding an encoded image to a web page. His explanation was easy enough to understand, however he did not explain how to encode the image in the first place.

So, I would like to know how do I encoding an image?

Thanks

Comment: What does this question have to do with its soup of tags? The short answer: [use a base64 encoder](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=base64+encoder). Could you pick a specific language?

Comment: It is indeed language specific

Comment: http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64 will create base64 representation of your image, given a URL. After that, throw some <img> html around it, and you're done.

Comment: If you want to embed images in CSS, I've created a tool (shameless plug) to do it automatically: http://code.google.com/p/css-image-embedder/

Comment: I was not sure if it was language specific, so I did not know what language to tag

Answer (score 4):

Here's a php sample:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('somepic.jpg');
$base64 = base64_encode($data);

?>

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $base64 ?>" />
```

base64 is base64, no matter what OS you're on.

Answer (score 0):

You need a base64 encoder for that. Try for example http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp. Upload your image to the site and a base64 representation will be generated for you to cut-and-paste into your HTML.